# What is the best way to try Ubuntu out?

Tags: live-usb, live-environment

A friend of mine loves Ubuntu with Gnome, but doesn't want to install it (yet) and doesn't want to use wubi. When I used unetbootin to put an Ubuntu iso on his 2GB usb stick, it worked, but it didn't save anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friend simply wants to try Ubuntu, your friend can use a Virtual Machine. Two well known examples are:

```
VirtualBox
VMWare
```

[See the VirtualBox website for more information.](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

These act very similar to how you would expect an operating system to work, though you may find a few issues with functionality, including, according to some people, a lack of WiFi.

The alternative is to follow [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) on how to run Ubuntu via his pen drive. This will be more inline with what you are trying to achieve.

Good luck!